# JSDoc: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, typescript, annotations, jsdoc

I'm using vanilla JavaScript with [TypeScript as pre-processor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) in combination with [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/). 
That pretty much works flawlessly, especially in the backend (when using in NodeJS, for instance).

However, when I use it with DOM objects, things get a bit tricky.

For example: Say I have an HTML Input field, I catch the `input` event and want to access the input's value with `e.target.value`:

```js
/**
 * Log data on input
 *
 * @param {Event} e
 */
let handleEvent = function(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
};

document.getElementById("my-input").addEventListener("input", handleEvent);
```

This results in a TS warning:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

As seen here:

[image: TypeScript Warning]

Now my question is, what's the correct `@param` annotation?

So far I've tried `Event`, `InputEvent` and `HTMLInputElement`.

I don't want to use [Type-Assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066421/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget). Instead I'd like to know how to specify it in the functions annotations directly, so I do not have to set `@type` for each and every occurrence of `e.target.value` individually as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817856/jsdoc-javascript-language-service-how-to-annotate-an-expression-how-to-cast).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can write your `@param` annotation like that:

```js
/**
 * Log data on input
 *
 * @param {Event & { target: HTMLInputElement }} e
 */
let handleEvent = function(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
};
```

Then you get full support for the correct types:

[image: 1]

The reason why this works, is that you're basically "extending" the `Event` class by the new target property - which already exists, so it gets overridden with our new type.

The ampersand per se is not a jsdoc operator, but one from TypeScript. So this only works out if you keep using TypeScript as your preprocessor. See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Sadly not a lot less typing¹ than the type assertion. This approach is reasonable, but it has the feeling of a workaround. Still, if `Event`/`InputEvent` doesn't have a generic type parameter (and it seems not to), I'm not sure what else you'd do. ¹ *"typing" in the sense of pressing keys on a keyboard*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Imo it actually is less typing if you use `e` in the function body a lot. Doesn't feel like a workaround to me since I explicitly state the type of the parameter. The only "workaround" I could think of, would be accessing `this` instead of `e`. Nonetheless, I'm pretty happy with this solution :)

Comment: @NullDev  - You'd grab `target` to a local, once. `var target = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (e.target);` But this `&` solution is **very** nearly the same as using a generic type parameter (actually, now I think about it, I'm not sure what the type parameter would offer other than a bit more conciseness), so seems pretty good. :-)

Comment: As you mentioned, it just workd with TypeScript, not pure JS only with JSDoc.
In this case the trick works on the function, but not when calling it in `addEventListener( handleEvent )`.
Let's assume we want to use target and originalTarget.
JSDoc outputs this error on the parameter:

**Argument of type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent & { originalTarget: HTMLInputElement; target: HTMLInputElement; }'.
  Property 'originalTarget' is missing in type 'MouseEvent' but required in type '{ originalTarget: HTMLInputElement; target: HTMLInputElement; }'.ts(2345)**